# Quelques questions concernant les articles

Tags: articles

J'ai lu bien des grammaires ; cependant plusieurs fois je n'arrive pas à comprendre l'emploi des articles et les utiliser correctement. Voici quelques cas indicatifs:

> 1. **Les dernières miettes du pain (Mérimée)**. Pourquoi emploie-t-on *du pain* et pas *de pain* ? Est-ce de +le qui donne du ? En revanche, de+du (article partitif) ne dégénère pas à de ?
> 2. **As-tu acheté des pommes ?**  Ici *des* est un article indéfini ou partitif ?
> 3. **On ne trouve au marché, ni œufs, ni légumes, ni fromage (France).**
>
>    **Ce n'est ni de la soie ni du coton.** Pourquoi dans la seconde
>      phrase, l'article partitif ne s’omet pas ?
> 4. **On ne disait rien du pain.** Pourquoi *du pain* et pas *de pain* ?
> 5. **Je ne parle pas des rats dans la maison** (Camus). Même question. Pourquoi *des* ne devient pas de ?
> 6. **Un effet curieux du hasard** (Verne). Quelle est la raison pour l'emploi de *du* ?
> 7. **Un collier de perles**. Pourquoi *de* et pas *des* ?
> 8. **Vêtus de robes blanches.** Même question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Les deux sont possibles. Avec *du*, on insiste sur le fait qu'il s'agit des miettes d'un pain précis, celui dont proviennent ces dernières miettes, et donc pas de n'importe quel pain.
2. Indéfini, le partitif aurait été, As-tu acheté de la pomme...
3. Par ce que "de la soie" est attribut du sujet. cf. http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/061.html
4. Parce que *pain* n'est pas un adjectif...
5. Parce qu'il s'agit de rats précis, ceux qui sont présents dans la maison. *je ne parle pas de xxx* est une antiphrase (on dit le contraire de ce qu'on veut dire). La phrase avec *de* est possible, mais dans ce cas, ce n'est plus une antiphrase et les rats ne sont pas forcément dans la maison. *Je ne parle pas de rats dans la maison*: les rats sont un sujet de conversation que je n'aborde pas quand je suis à la maison.
6. Peut-être parce qu'il n'y a qu'un hasard.
7. Parce que ces perles ne sont pas définies. C'est simplement la nature du collier d'être fait de perles.
8. Il ne s'agit pas de robes blanche précises donc article indéfini. Avec *des*, on aurait éventuellement pu dire: *Elles étaient vêtues des robes blanches que j'avais apportées*